# Query builder that works with all major databases?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oracle

I need to use a query builder that generates SQL statements containing placeholders.

It should:

- Generate SQL statements containing placeholders(:placeHolder or ?)
- Have **no** object mapping
- Return the query as a string or similar
- Work with all major databases(e.g. Oracle, MySQL)

I am thinking about something like this:

```
QueryBuilder::select(
    'db' => 'MySQL'
    'from' => 'users',
    'fields' => array(
         'user_id' => 'id'
    ),
    'where' => array(
        'AND' => array(
             /**
              * ...conditions...
              */
        )
    ),
    'ljoin' => array(
        'Group' => array(
            'from' => 'groups'
             /**
              * ...stuff...
              */
        )
    )
);
```

I looked into Doctrine2 but it needs object mapping. And a lot of initial configuration.
I looked into Doctrine2 DBAL and it does not handle INSERT queries.

*Note:* Queries are generated in development stage and saved as plain text for each supported database engine.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: AFAIK a lot of frameworks have similar tools or active record classes that do this sort of thing.  Off the top of my head, I know that CI and Yii both have something similar, but then again, you need to have a big chunk of the framework for it to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Doctrine 2 ORM Query builder very versatile and works with most DBMS systems more at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

Comment: You need to have the object mappings so that the Query Builder can traverse the relationships to build the joins

Answer (score 0):

An example is the Code Igniter [Active Record](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html), you can build querys like:

```
$this->db->select('field_one, field_two')
    ->from('mytable')
    ->where(array('field' => 'value', 'field' => 'value'))
```

Comment: Can I use it outside the framework? Can I get the query and not actually execute it?

Comment: Use `last_query()` to get the last query. I never use it outside the CI, but you can see the source of the classes (core/database folder) and adapt for what you need.